# Does vPro require an Intel NIC?

Tags: networking, hp

I'm looking at some HP Elite 7000 desktops.  The web page for these machines imply that they have vPro support.  However, the ones I'm looking at buying have Realtek NICs.  I'm assuming that they're not vPro ready?  I notice that there is an Intel NIC option for this model...they're not making it easy for me to figure out which SKUs have vPro and which don't. Any insight?

I'll give them a call, but I want to know if my assumptions are correct first.

Answer (score 2):

Intel vPro technology is a set of features built into a PC’s motherboard and other hardware. Intel vPro is not the PC itself, nor is it a single set of management features (such as Intel Active Management Technology (Intel AMT)) for sys-admins. Intel vPro is a combination of processor technologies, hardware enhancements, management features, and security technologies that allow remote access to the PC.

It doesn't matter what network card you are using, as long as the bios on the computer supports the network card directly, and if HP are tell you it's vPro compatible, it will be.

Hardware requirements for desktop PCs with Intel vPro

Desktop PCs with vPro (called “Intel Core 2 with vPro technology”) require:

```
* For AMT release 5.0:
      o Intel Core2 Duo processor E8600, 8500, and E8400 ; 45nm Intel Core2 Quad processor Q9650, Q9550, and Q9400.
      o Intel Q45 (Eaglelake-Q) Express Chipset with ICH10DO.
* For AMT release 3.0, 3.1, and 3.2:
      o Intel Core2 Duo processor E6550, E6750, and E6850; 45nm Intel Core2 Duo processor E8500, E8400, E8300 and E8200; 45nm Intel Core2 Quad processor Q9550, Q9450 and Q9300.
      o Intel Q35 (Bearlake-Q) Express Chipset with ICH9DO.
```

Note that AMT release 2.5 for wired/wireless laptops and AMT release 3.0 for desktop PCs are concurrent releases.

```
* For AMT release 2.0, 2.1 and 2.2:
      o Intel Core 2 Duo processor E6300, E6400, E6600, and E6700.
      o Intel Q9655 (Averill) Express Chipset with ICH8DO.
```

Taken from [Wikipedia] so you get all the facts.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_vPro)

Comment: Well AMT is what I'm interested in.  Those required controller hubs all appear to have built in gigabit ethernet.  Thus I'm guessing that you have to have the entire Intel stack for all vPro features to work.

Answer (score 0):

After a fair bit of searching around I can't find anything conclusive one way or the other about this, certainly HP heavily hint that it's vPro-capable but they don't exactly pronounce on the subject. If you're really that bothered I'd try superuser.com (where this question should really have been aimed at originally to be honest but never mind).

Comment: Thanks.  I posted this question here because it's related to client management, which in my mind is closer to "serverfault" than "superuser".